# Alle form posts just refreshing page

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I received an e-mail earlier today telling me that all the contact-forms on a website 'suddenly' stopped working. I checked it out and I notice that all form posts are just refreshing the page as if no post had been done. (No notices, no errors etc.) It's a Wordpress website so I wanted to log into the backpanel, but the login post-form, seems to have the exact same problem. The page refreshes as if no post-action has been done. What could cause such a site-wide malfunction of the post action?

(I tried activating the PHP errors, but nothing comes up)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you check the PHP error logs? Is it possible that your database is not running? Do you have root access to the host or is it managed by someone else?

Comment: Open developer tools, check 1> the form html, 2> the network tab when you make a post

Comment: @DaveChen -> Database is running or WP wouldn't work entirely. I do not have root access. It's a simple managed hosting package.

Comment: @Steve -> Fired up Fiddler. A POST request is sent with the filled in variables. But then... nothing. You could take a look if you want: www. stomerij 2 go .nl (erase the spaces)

Comment: Hmm, very strange - i cant see any obvious problems - no redirects or similar. Have you tried just opening a support ticket with the host? Also see if there is anything odd in your htaccess file

Comment: @Steve, thanks for taking a look. Deleted everything non-vital from the htaccess, but to no avail. I think I'll just open a ticket with my hosting provider.